# iOS big integer NSNumberFormatter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, number-formatting, biginteger

I am working with big integer number in my iOS project. I don't have any conversion problem issue because i'm keeping all the number in string. But i am facing issue when i apply NSNumberFormatter in the string. Suppose i have the string with 40+ digit. 
My code is like:

```
 // lastString_Capital is my string of all digit. let it 55252585858585858552525251232581285224 (38+)
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
 NSString *text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:[lastString_Capital longLongValue]]];
```

I know that the range (numberWithUnsignedLongLong) exceed the limit of my current number. I need a solution to formate this long number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSDecimalNumber`. Your value is far too big for a `long long` value.

```
NSDecimalNumber *bigNum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:lastString_Capital];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:bigNum];
```

Comment: Please help me for 55252585858585858552525251232581285224 (38 digit) this number. If i enter more digit with this, it's adding all zero in the end. May be i need more big number format.

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber` only supports up to 38 digits of precision and that is the best you are going to be able to format. There is no Cocoa API provided by Apple that will let you get any more precision than that.

Comment: Yes. i was thinking same of you. Thanks for reply.